# I've got a Unexpected non-void return value in void function error?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, switch-statement

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section {
    case 0:
```

redeclaration of a var statement

```
        one = Database.database().reference()
```

collecting information from database

```
        one.child("users").child("profile").observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
            let num = snapshot.childrenCount
```

where the error arises

```
            return Int(num)
        })
    default:
        return 0
    }

}
```

Comment: In general, you can't return values from Firebase closures as they are not functions and attempting to maintain a tableView directly from Firebase (over the internet) is it's going to be laggy. See below comments.

Comment: Are you sure you want to read *all* of the nodes in /users/profile? Generally it would be /users/uid/profile to get data for a single user.

Answer (score 1):

This function that you're passing to observe is typed as a function that returns void:

```
{(snapshot) in
    let num = snapshot.childrenCount
    return Int(num)
})
```

You can see from the API docs for [observe](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseReference#observe_with):

> **Declaration**
>
> ```
> func observe(_ eventType: DataEventType, with block: @escaping (DataSnapshot) -> Void) -> UInt
> ```

The type of the function is `(DataSnapshot) -> Void`, which means that it can not return a value.  But you're returning `Int(num)` instead.

You won't be able to return the result of a database query from collectionView() because the database observer is asynchronous and returns immediately.  It will give you a value some time later, and you have no guarantee how long it will take.

Answer (score 1):

Doug Stevenson is right!

What you can do instead is after you get your data from server, parse it and save it to a variable and update your collectionView.

```
var data = [YourModel]()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

Database.database().reference().child("users").child("profile").observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in

    let values = snapshot.values as? [String: Any] else { return }

    var tmpArrayOfValues = [YourModel]()

    // here you create YourModel objects
    values.forEach { (item) in
        let newItem = //create your item from values
        tmpArrayOfValues.append(newItem)
    }    

    self.data = tmpArrayOfValues

    // to update UI you have to return to main thread, because firebase func are running on background thread
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that DispatchQueue is unneeded as UI calls within Firebase closures are performed on the main thread and there's not reason to populate a tempArray - the class level self.data array can be populated directly. You may want to adjust this code to be .observeSingleEvent as .value leaves an observer on the node to watch for changes and it seems the OP just wants to get it one time.